# Views Infinite Scroll and back button issue

Tags: paging, views

I am using [Views Infinite scroll](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_infinite_scroll) module, Drupal 7. When i click on an item and go to next page and then click Browser back button, it takes me back to the start of the page.

When i click browser back button, i want the user to go back where he clicked/ or where he was on the previous page

Can somebody suggest any solution to this? Or any other module that can be used? Or an jquery script that would help?

I am badly in need of help.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [GD Infinite Scroll](https://www.drupal.org/project/gd_infinite_scroll) module.

> Provide an administration to use the infinite scroll jQuery plugin :
>   auto-pager on custom pages using pager. You can use autoload on scroll
>   or a load more button. This module is designed to works on any page
>   with pagination (views, search results, heavily customised page, ...)